# Change in moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

On 7 September, [Robert Cartaino♦](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/robert-cartaino) made the [Moderator Pro Tem Announcement](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/moderator-pro-tem-announcement/), listing as moderators:

> [image: Chealion] [image: Studer] [image: Dori] [image: Kyle Cronin]

#### But now…

When I look at our [About page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/about) today, I see the moderators listed as:

> [image: Curr mods]

I was surprised to not see an announcement/acknowledgement here of some sort, so I figured I'd post one. <sup><sub>(you're soaking in it!)</sub></sup>

@Chealion, many thanks for your hard work! (and please don't leave us altogether)

@Calavera, congrats on the promotion!

Comment: @Calavera : Gratz! :)

Comment: Martin: thanks!  Now I'm +1/-1 for positive to negative posts on meta about me :)

Comment: lol... like you said, it's a badge of honor :)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>I’m adding an answer although it is kind of unrelated to the “question”. **"tip o’ the antler" to Calavera for teaching me the ‘sub' tag**</sub>

I’d love to help moderate, but my English is not native and as such, I usually make mistakes and I don’t think it would be a good idea. In any case, if we *really* need another one, I would gladly help, especially if the site’s traffic starts increasing and “moderation” workload is increased.

Just have me as candidate on hold. :)

Comment: I think your English is better than mine in many cases...

Comment: @calavera :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When I noticed that Chealion was no longer a moderator and that Studer hasn't even visited the site in two months, I contacted Robert and recommended calavera for the position. He's been really active on the main site, here on meta, he frequently flagged stuff for moderator attention, and he's taken an active role in [trying to clean up the site](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194/question-deletion/196#196).

Congratulations on the promotion calavera - you've earned it!

Comment: thanks for the nomination, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

The announcement simply trailed behind the appointment. No slight intended. Congratulations to @calavera and thank you for stepping up! The moderator announcement has been updated:

[Moderator Pro Tem Announcement](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/moderator-pro-tem-announcement)

Comment: but I think it's better to change Studer not Chealion, anyway congratz @calavera

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: Chealion was not "changed." He requested to step down for personal reasons. Studer has not been active but he still retains his moderator abilities and is always welcome to return. The linked post contains the list of the current moderator team.